# Have my Mac wake me up

Tags: audio, calendar, alarm, macos, alert

I am currently a thousand miles away from home and will be for 2 months more. Today, another bad thing appended on my Weekend, locking myself out of my mobile, since I wrote the PIN wrongly 3 times. However, tomorrow I will have to go to work, how am I going to wake up?!

I went to Calendar and set up an event with a message with sound, but this does only make a *very short* sound and pops up a screen notification. These two are unlikely to wake me up.

***How to tell my laptop to behave like an alarm clock?***

---

I am not worried at all for energy consumption at the moment and I have my laptop charging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the Mac App Store and search for "Alarm Clock". Take your pick from the many apps that will do the job.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a reliable internet connection, you can try [this site](http://www.timer-tab.com), which has Countdown, Alarm and Stopwatch modes.

My brother uses [this free (with in-app upgrades) OS X app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/alarm-clock/id755731884?mt=12) available in the App Store.